# PowerBuilder Changing button text depending on database column value

Tags: sql, database, powerbuilder

In my database I have a column where default_column_value = 1.
I currently have a button that displays the text "Pay Enabled". When clicked, this button toggles the column value between 1 and 0.  When the column value is at 1 the button should display "Pay Enabled" When it is at 0 it should display "Pay Disabled".  What is the best way to achieve this?

Below is the window where I have programmatically added the button.

```
btn_add("Pay Enabled", true)
```

btn_add()

```
ii_blank_btns += 1
blank_btns[ii_blank_btns].object.t_text.y = 50
blank_btns[ii_blank_btns].object.t_text.text = as_name
blank_btns[ii_blank_btns].object.c_color.expression = '0'
blank_btns[ii_blank_btns].GroupCalc()
blank_btns[ii_blank_btns].visible = true
```

[Properties Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7VNw.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use a datawindow button, that is a button defined in the datawindow.
In the properties of that button, click on the 'Expression' icon of the text and put something like `if(col_value = 1, 'Payment Enabled', 'Payment Disabled')`.
See hereunder the 'Expression' button is on the right of the text 'none' and contains the expression above.
[image]

Comment: When I click on properties I only see "Text".  Where do I find 'Expression' of the text?

Comment: Added an image to make it clearer.

Comment: I've also added an image of my properties box.  Looks a bit different than yours. Do I write the conditional where the "Text" box is?

Comment: Just an FYI this is a command button that I inserted into my main window.  Is that different than a datawindow button? Sorry if the question is simple I am very new to powerbuilder.

Comment: Marc is describing a button inside a DataWindow; you have a button control on a window. Marc is describing the only automagic solution. For a command button control, you’ll just have to monitor when the value changes (ItemChanged if the value is in a DW) and code your own text change.